# The app references non-public selectors getAuthorizationStatus from App Store connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a IOS build for React Native 0.70 app to `App Store connect` via Xcode 14 and at the end it throws an error:

```
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/xyz_app6.app/xyz_app6: getAuthorizationStatus:, onSuccess:
```

[image]

The build was uploaded successfully in App Store connect. Some online posts claim that the error is related to configuration in Xcode for the project and the build is not safe to publish. What configuration it may be for the error above? There is no location service enabled/disabled or 3rd party auth used in the app.

Comment: have you found a solution?